# Jquery append - Image inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add images to a div. When the images append. The are displaying "block". I need them to display inline.

This is the code I am running:

```
$(".showvideothumbs").append($('<img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" style="display:inline">').hide().fadeIn(2000));
```

I've tried wrapping it in a div that has "display:inline" set, but jquery changes that to "display:block".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback.

```
$(".showvideothumbs").append('&lt;img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" style="display:none;"/&gt;').find('img').fadeIn(2000,function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline style try

```
.css('display', 'inline')
```

Comment: I tried adding it like: $(".showvideothumbs").append($('<img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" ').hide().fadeIn(2000).css('display','inline')); But that adds the "inline" to .showvideothumbs not the image. Is there a better place to add it?

Comment: The "display:block" css value is use by jQuery to process the fadeIn animation. You have to use the callback function to update the css value at the end of the animation. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to why you are doing this:

```
$('<img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" style="display:inline">').hide().fadeIn(2000)
```

You are, in effect, creating an image and then hiding and showing it before it is even added to the DOM.

Does setting the style using `.css('display', 'inline')` work more effectively for you?

```
$(".showvideothumbs").append($('<img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" style="display:inline">').css('display', 'inline'));
```

You can then apply the hide/fade to the containing DIV (formatted for greater ease of reading):

```
$(".showvideothumbs")
    .append($('<img src="/garageimages/'+data.thumb+'" style="display:inline">')
         .css('display', 'inline'))
    .hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: I was doing it that way so that I could load the image hidden and then fade it in. Your solution works, except it hides the whole div and then fades it back in, but you inline solution does work.