# Append images inline using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images where the src gets fetched from the database. For each record in the list it creates an image and append it to a div.

The images get displayed fine and correctly but the problem is that all images get displayed underneath each other. I want the images to get displayed next to each other (inline).

This is what I have:

Here I append my image to the div:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
        var clb = response.d;
        $(clb).each(function () {
            $('#myDiv').append('<img src=' + this.clubLogo + ' style="display: inline-block;" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/> ');
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section-body">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div id="myDiv">
           <%--Here is where my images get displayed underneath each other--%>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried implementing this solution but does not work for me:
[Jquery append - Image inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813708/jquery-append-image-inline)

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call `OnSuccess` function?

Comment: Perhaps `style="display: inline;"`

Comment: `style="display: inline;"` unfortunately doesn't work. I have tried almost every css suggest there is.

Comment: Difficult without seeing the css for all these random classes applied above. Have you tried defining a width for your images?

Comment: Yes I have. When I hard code multiple images through html it gets displayed inline which is what I want BUT as soon as I use my jquery function to display the imaged it all gets displayed underneath each other so the classes have nothing to do with the issues. I highly suspect that some extra styling need to be applied to the jQuery side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img>` tags are inline by default, so something is adding a `display:block` to them in order for them to render according to your description.

To solve that, this should work:

Make the container div into a flexbox parent:

```
class="flex-parent"
```

Where `.flex-parent` has the CSS rule:

```
.flex-parent{display:flex;}
```

In the below code example, I put `display:block` onto the `.thumbnail` class - that made the images appear in a column. Leaving `.thumbnail` like that, I added the `flex-parent` class (call it whatever you want) onto the container div, and *Le Voila!* true happiness is found.

```css
.thumbnail{display:block;}

.flex-parent{display:flex;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" class="flex-parent">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>
</div>
```

---

Flexbox is really super-simple. It requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

You turn flexbox ***on*** on the parent: `display:flex;`

Then, there are various *switches*. Some are set on the parent (as in the case of `justify-content`) but others might be set on the items (as with `flex-grow:1`)

[YouTube tutorial - fast-paced and best-of-breed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) for Flexbox.

***Watch the tutorial and in 20 mins every problem you've ever had in your life will be solved -- and you'll know flexbox.***

<sub>P.S. I have no connection to the video or its presenter - I was fortunate to discover it, and now pass it along.</sub>

Note that the primary change from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4 was redesigning the core grid system ***around flexbox.*** That gives you an idea how important flexbox is.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you and thanks for the additional info. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just one question, Even though display:flex works and puts the images inline, there is a problem when testing on a mobile devices...the images stay inline. They loose responsive functionality. Any feedback on this?

Comment: You can use a [javascript media query](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp) to remove the `flex-parent` class if the max-width is under a certain size (900px?). *(Same as using CSS media queries, but you can do more than just CSS...)*

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just forgott the double quotes at the src attribute.

your code:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<img src=' + this.clubLogo + ' ...
```

how it should look like:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<img src="' + this.clubLogo + '" ...
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have applied it

Answer (score 2):

Try add to your code

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
```

and in js

```
$('#myDiv').append('<img src=' + this.clubLogo + ' style="width: 50%;" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/> ');
```

instead

```
$('#myDiv').append('<img src=' + this.clubLogo + ' style="display: inline-block;" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/> ');
```

if it works, move the inline styles to the css file.